# Regular expressions: all words after my current one are gone

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I need to remove all strings from my text file, such as:

```
flickr:user=32jdisffs
flickr:user=acssd
flickr:user=asddsa89
```

I'm currently using `fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll(" , flickr:user=.*", "");`

however the issue with this is approach is that any word after `flickr:user=` is removed from the content, even after the space.

thanks

Comment: Not clear from your question. Please post example of before and after that you expect.

Comment: There is a `g` flag which means 'greedy' and replaces as much as it can reach. Perhaps this is enabled by default.

Comment: @pim non-greedy won't help either, because it won't match enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need

`replaceAll("flickr:user=[0-9A-Za-z]+", "");`

Answer (score 0):

`flickr:user=\w+` should do it:

```
String noFlickerIdsHere = stringWithIds.replaceAll("flickr:user=\\w+", "");
```

**Reference:**

`\w` = A word character: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

Going by the question as stated, chances are that you want:

```
fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll(" , flickr:user=[^ ]* ", ""); // or " "
```

This will match the string, including the value of `user` up to but not including the first space, followed by a space, and replace it either by a blank string, or a single space. **However** this will (barring the comma) net you an empty result with the input you showed. Is that really what you want?

I'm also not sure where the `" , "` at the beginning fits into the example you showed.

The reason for your difficulties is that an unbounded `.*` will match everything from that point up until the end of the input (even if that amounts to nothing; that's what the `*` is for). For a line-based regular expression parser, that's to the end of the line.