# Regular expressions: how to remove machine tags from my tags list

Tags: java, regex

I've a sequence of tags and I only need to remove those tags having the following structure:

```
*:*:*
```

They are machine tags such as: flickr:event:132394 and not user submitted tags. What regular expression should I use ?

```
fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll(" ,.*:.*", "");
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103251/regular-expressions-all-words-after-my-current-one-are-gone

Comment: Why do you have a comma in your regexp? Is it part of the format?

Comment: You can try fields[i].replaceAll(".*:", "") maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll("\\w+:\\w+:\\w+", "");`

if the words consist of letters and digits only.
To be safer you can even say:

`fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll("[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+", "");`

that will remove all characters that are not colon.
The only problem is with the last section. How can you know that the last word is finished? There is no colon there. If for example you wish to remove all characters that are not whitespace, say:

`fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll("[^:]+:[^:]+:\\S+", "");`

Comment: Your second version also matches this: "some:tag  some:othertag some:thirdtag". `[^:]+` is way to greedy!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll("\\w+:\\w+:\\w+", "");
```

(See [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103251/regular-expressions-all-words-after-my-current-one-are-gone/5103288#5103288) for explanation)

Or, if you also need to deal with commas (and perhaps white space), use this version:

```
fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll("\\s*,?\\s*\\w+:\\w+:\\w+", "");
```